# Java not detected by browser

Tags: browser, java, jdk, jre

I have java installed on my computer, but none of my browsers seem to detect it a and I'm not able to run any applets. (Trivial, as it may seem) I've wasted a lot of time googling and trying to troubleshoot this issue unsuccessfully.

This is the output of the `java -version` command

```
C:\Users\kraj>java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

I'm able to write java programs and run them, Eclipse is running successfully as well - but the only problem is that none of my browsers (chrome, firefox, opera) are not able to detect java. The [java website](https://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp) to check java installation in a system is also not detecting java installed in my system. Really appreciate any help/pointers regarding this.

Comment: Reinstalling Java might save you the time and effort of getting to the actual issue. :)

Comment: Checking the JAVA_HOME and PATH env variables isn't so long, though.

Comment: There is often a configuration option on a browser to enable (or disable) applets.

Comment: Hm, this question has just been migrated... You have to create an account here if you want to accept an answer. ;)

Answer (score 8):

You have 64-bit Java installed. As most browsers do not come in a 64-bit version yet (this is at least true for Firefox), they are not able to use the 64-bit Java plugin.

If you want to use Java in your 32-bit browsers, you have to install 32-bit Java as well.

Note: It's no problem to have 32-bit Java installed along with your 64-bit version. That way, you may still use the 64-bit version of Eclipse for instance. However, you might have to choose the right VM in `eclipse.ini` explicitly. See [this Wiki entry](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example) for more information.

Comment: Most isn't all...Chrome is 64-bit, and you can download [nightly 64-bit versions of Firefox for Linux.](http://nightly.mozilla.org/)  Other than that, pretty much spot-on.

Comment: I'll try it now, and hope it works!

Comment: IE has also had a 64-bit variant available (since version 8 or 9 IIR).  However, many popular plugins are only available in 32-bit form -- not just Flash, but things like spyware/malware protection -- which may explain why 32-bit browsers are hanging on.

Answer (score 2):

You have 64-bit Java installed, and the web browser(s) that you are using are most likely 32-bit programs.

Install the 32-bit version of Java.

Answer (score 0):

Run this script to verify your situation:

```
@ECHO off
java -version
ECHO ---------------
SET "JAVA_HOME=C:\Path to wherever\JDKwhatever"
SET "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
firefox.exe http://website.with.java
::  iexplore.exe http://website.with.java
pause
```

Answer (score -1):

Java Verify failure  unable to Configure Java Control Panel does not open ( Fix : ) 
this is a regular ( windows 7 bug related ) problem after successful installation of Java ( jre ) and fresh installation of Windows7 64bit or 32bit on my laptop or desktop.  what worked perfectly for me was setting  COMPATIBILITYMODE=WINDOWSNT  to make windows launch the JP2LAUNCHER.EXE  and  JAVAW.EXE  files properly.
jp2launcher.exe windowsNT compatibility solves Java Verify failure problem at  https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp
javaw.exe windowsNT compatibility solves unable to open or Configure Java Control Panel problem.

```
*  search for JAVAW.EXE   inside  c:\program files\java\....\bin   
      or  c:\program files(x86)\java\.....\bin\
*  right-click mouse on  JAVAW   application icon logo
*  click  PROPERTIES
*  click  COMPATIBILITY
*  tick the checkbox at COMPATIBILITY MODE
*  choose  WINDOWS NT service pack
*  click APPLY or click OK
```

Now, the Configure Java Control Panel will start opening and working.

```
*  search for JP2LAUNCHER.EXE   inside  c:\program files\java\....\bin   
      or  c:\program files(x86)\java\.....\bin\
*  right-click mouse on  JP2LAUNCHER
*  click  PROPERTIES
*  click  COMPATIBILITY
*  tick the checkbox at COMPATIBILITY MODE
*  choose  WINDOWS NT service pack
*  click APPLY or click OK
```

Now, the Verify Java will be successful at  https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

if we find 2 or 3 versions of JP2LAUNCHER and JAVAW when we search, then we must repeat the above for all of them.

in the Configure Java Control Panel Advanced tab we can set "Do not check" certificate revocation and disable security verification. and in the Security tab we may Edit Site List... for the Exception Site List  ( add URLs to  unblock sites )